# Open a script (.js) from Node.js

Tags: node.js, function, locate

So my task is this

Write a JavaScript program numbers1to10.js that prints on the console the numbers from 1 to 10 (each at a separate line). Run the program through Node.js. Example:

Command: node numbers1to10.js

Output:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

I wrote the .js file called numbers1to10.js

```
function print1to10() {
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}}
```

But i cant seem to open i trought nod.js

What do i have to do?

Answer (score 1):

You don't call your function
Try:

```
function print1to10() {
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}}
print1to10();
```

Comment: Do you try to run it directly from within Visual Studio? If so then please try it by using a vanilla cmd.exe and running 'node 1.js' in the directory of 1.js as I assume your issue is caused by the IDE. I tried it both on Mac and Windows and it prints 1 to 10 on separate lines as expected ...

Comment: You try to start node from  ... node (your terminal show that is node ...)
Open CMD and type "Node PathOfYourFile"